# How to do a post request in ReactNative with formData

Tags: react-native, fetch

I need do a post request with fetch
like this
[in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMsXz.png).

And what I've tried :

```
 let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('username', String(username));
      formData.append('password', String(password));
  let init = {
    method: 'POST',
    header:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
   body: formData
}
  fetch(url, init)
```

It's successful in Postman but failed with fetch that return a 400 error with no param. Hope some helps , thanks

So I changed my code

```
 var details = {
          'username': '123',
          'password': '123',
      };
      var formBody = [];
      for (var property in details) {
      var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
      var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
      formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
     }
      formBody = formBody.join("&");

      let init = {
        method: 'POST',
        header:{
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
       body: formBody
    }
      fetch(url, init)
```

But get a same error

console the formBody:

```
username=123&password=123
```

My headers key was wrong ,that was the fault

should be:

```
let init = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
           body: formBody
        }
```

instead of

```
let init = {
                method: 'POST',
                header:{
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
               body: formBody
            }
```

Comment: I find that my content-type become "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" in the request.But I still don't know why.

Comment: My heads key was wrong . That was the fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status code 400 means you sent a bad request, i.e. the server expected something else.

In this case you're sending raw `multipart/form-data` (the first option in Postman), while you say you are sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` in your headers.

Since you'll want to use the latter according to your Postman screenshot, you have to send your body in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Comment: How can I format my body in x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Comment: How to send your body in x-www-form-urlencoded is a different question, but you'll probably find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562814/3990318)