# How to post a x-www-form-urlencoded data properly using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have written a JS function to post categoryId and shopId and page:0 to an api and this is my funciton :-

```
 getInsideMenu(categoryid,shopid){
        var formBody = [];
        var details={
             'categoryId':categoryid,
             'shopId':shopid ,
             'page':'0'
        };
        for (var property in details) {
              var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
              var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
              formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
        }
                return fetch(
            `${serverAddress}/api/shopProducts`,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formBody,
                headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }
        ).then((res)=>(res.json()))
    },
```

But I'm getting null .I suppose the function is not defined properly. What can be done to fix it. It works well in POSTMAN.
[![this is in postman how I send][1]][1]

Comment: Try with `body: formBody.join('&')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're building an array of encoded name/value pairs and passing that directly as the `body` of the POST. But [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) doesn't accept an array in that parameter.

The minimal change to your code would be to join the array using `&` as the separator:

```
return fetch(
    `${serverAddress}/api/shopProducts`,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formBody.join("&"), // <===== here
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }
). /* etc */
```

Alternately, use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), as this is exactly what it's for: :-)

```
getInsideMenu(categoryid,shopid){
    var formBody = new FormData();
    formBody.set("categoryId", categoryid);
    formBody.set("shopId", shopid);
    formBody.set("page", "0");
    return fetch(
        `${serverAddress}/api/shopProducts`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formBody,
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }
    ).then((res)=>(res.json()));
}
```

(Depending on your needs, you might use [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set) or [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append). The above uses `set`.)

---

#### Side note 1:

This line:

```
).then((res)=>(res.json()));
```

...doesn't need most of those `()`:

```
).then(res => res.json());
```

#### Side note 2:

Don't forget to check for success; failing to do so is a common pitfall when using `fetch`. `fetch` **doesn't** reject on HTTP error (like 404 or 500). If you want to reject on HTTP error, you have to do it yourself:

```
return fetch(/*...*/)
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(res.status);
        }
        return res;
    })
    .then(res => res.json());
```

Comment: everything seems fine but in the data that I m getting back two array values are null shopProductsCount and shopProducts....but the other values seems to be right I mean like responseResult etc

Comment: @hearty - Fairly certain that will be an unrelated issue.

Answer (score -2):

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325370/post-a-x-www-form-urlencoded-request-from-react-native?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

You have to insert at least `formBody = formBody.join("&");` after the loop.

Comment: If the answer to that question answers this question (and I think you're right, it does), vote to close as duplicate, don't post a link to the answer in an answer.