# How do I POST data and parameters like in Axios, using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch, axios

Take the following Axios example:

```
axios.post(this.reportURL, reportData, {
  params: {
    param1: paramValue1,
    param2: paramValue2
  },
});
```

How can I do the same thing using fetch API?  I see that parameters are done like this:

```
fetch(this.reportURL, {
  method: "POST",
  body: "param1=paramValue1&param2=paramValue2",
  headers: 
    {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }

})
```

Since the body key is being used to store the parameters, do I need to serialize my entire reportData object and concatenate it to the existing parameters?

I don't understand why Fetch API is using the body key for parameters.

Additionally, this is not my own API and I cannot change the expected POST request.

Comment: Unless I am misreading the axios docs, those are not same.  The first, will append those params as a URL params i.e. `example.com?p1=foo&p2=bar`.  The second will append the body as the actual body of the request, not as part of the URL.  Which one are you *trying* to do.

Comment: You cannot `extract` the pieces you need from reportData and create your own object to pass to `fetch`? What do you mean you cannot change the POST request?

Comment: @zero298 I am trying to do both, as the API requires parameters as well as JSON data.

Comment: @Akrion I can create my own object, I guess I am wondering if what you suggested is indeed the correct approach to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frustratingly, `fetch()` does not really provide a "clean" way to provide query string URL parameters.  You have to just put them in the URL that you are fetching directly.  It's a point of contention that you can read about on the GitHub: [How to pass url query params? #256](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/256).

There are a few ways that you can simulate it:

```js
const url = new URL("http://www.example.com");

const params = {
  foo: "bar",
  fizz: "buzz"
};

const data = {
  more: "data",
  that: "I",
  want: "to",
  send: "please"
};

Object.entries(params).forEach(([k, v]) => url.searchParams.append(k, v));
console.log(url);

fetch(url, { // URL as http://www.example.com/?foo=bar&fizz=buzz
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(data) // The actual body
});
```

Since you have `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in your question as well, you may want to take a look at this question also: [Post a x-www-form-urlencoded request from React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562814/691711).

Comment: Thanks for the github discussion, that was quite helpful. The x-www-form-urlencoded content-type header was unintentional; I pasted from another example sorry about the confusion. As I move our application from Axios to fetch it seems like there are more than a few hurdles I need to overcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to construct query param string from a hash and you use jQuery on your site, you can do:

`var url = "http://www.abx.com?" + $.param({foo: "bar", baz: "kuuq"})
fetch(url)`

Here is what the fetch standard recommends in their documentation (also see discussion in whatwg/fetch#56):

`var url = new URL("https://geo.example.org/api"),
    params = {lat:35.696233, long:139.570431}
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
fetch(url).then(...)`

This requires that the browser implements url.searchParams. A polyfill might be needed for older browsers.

*Read over this quickly, but hopefully that helped*

Src: https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/256

Answer (score 0):

You can do
    `body: JSON.stringify({
        param1: paramValue1,
        param2: paramValue2
    })`

Comment: But then the data wouldn't be sent

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're close, but on the second example, as you're making a POST request, the parameters will usually go on the body of the request as JSON:

```
fetch(this.reportURL, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    param1: paramValue1,
    param2: paramValue2
  })    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `extract` the pieces from `reportData` into another object and pass that one to `fetch` by JSON.stringify it.

Fetch also supports `FormData` but that is not that much different that the object approach I already mentioned.

As [per the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body) you could specify the **body** as the following:

1. ArrayBuffer
2. ArrayBufferView (Uint8Array and friends)
3. Blob/File
4. string
5. URLSearchParams
6. FormData