# Getting false response and empty data array in react-native post save data to server

Tags: react-native, post, fetch-api

I am trying to save a simple registration form to server using `fetch` but getting response `false`.

```
apiDataSave = () => {
         fetch('<myapi>', {  
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name : "abc",
                no : "1234567890",
                password : "123",
                email : "abc@gmail.com"  
            })
          })
          .then(function(response) {
              return response.json();
            })
          .then(function(data) {
              alert(`response json is: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)
          })

}
```

I am getting alert as follows:

> response json is: {"status":false,"data":[]}

The expected result alert is:

> response json is: {"status":true,"data":"1"}  // number of records entered in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `Content-Type` was not `'application/json'` but following:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
```

I got the answer here:
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562814/9981182)