# fetch function returns 400 bad request error for content-type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Tags: reactjs, fetch, http-status-code-400

This question has been asked before but those solutions i have already tried and i shall 
explain along the way.

**Task:**
I want to send data to api with content-type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

**Problem:**
The URL works fine in Postman and returns me the correct response. When i try the same body parameters through my Reactjs app, it responds with 400 bad request error.

**What i have tried:**

```
myBody:{
grant_type:"XYZ",
client_id:"XYZ"
}
var request = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            method: "POST",
            body:myBody
        };
```

Then i fetch something like this.

```
const data = yield fetch(complete_url,request);
```

I also tried to compose myBody as a [formData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325370/post-a-x-www-form-urlencoded-request-from-react-native#:~:text=var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20method%3A%20',Do%20stuff%20with%20result%20%7D)%3B) . Still gives the same error.

Apologies i have not given the URL because of restrictions. I am looking for possibilities of errors i could make.

Comment: Refer to this since you have to build the URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325370/post-a-x-www-form-urlencoded-request-from-react-native

Answer (score -1):

With `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`,
Your request body should follow certain rule (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST).
`the keys and values are encoded in key-value tuples separated by '&', with a '=' between the key and the value`,
example:
`grant_type =value1&client_id=value2`. 
So i suggest what it looks like in debugger -> network tab.

If the request body is not a problem. Then you should check if there's any special chars.
You also will need to escape symbols and special chars.

Comment: i have tried it but not working. I really think it should work. i dont know why its not wokrking

Comment: Can you copy as curl for both the request made by postman and by javascript?