# Pass Data to Service in Axios

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

I want to set `_boundry` in my header.

First, I dispatch the form data:

```
//component.js

const form = new FormData();

form.append('email', 'eray@serviceUser.com')
form.append('password', '12121212')

dispatch(FetchLogin.action(form))
```

Second, I prepare api call;

```
//loginService.js

import api from '@/Services'

export default async form => {
  const response = await api.post('user/login/', form)
  return response.data
}
```

Third, I make api call;

```
//Services/index.js

import axios from 'axios'
import { Config } from '@/Config'

const instance =  axios.create({
  baseURL: Config.API_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`, //Cannot access form here
  }, 
  timeout: 3000,
})

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  ({ message, response: { data, status } }) => {
    return handleError({ message, data, status })
  },
)

export default instance
```

I want to access `form` data within to `axios` `instance` to be able to use `form._boundry` in `headers`.

How can I pass `form` data from `loginService.js` to `Services/index.js`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When performing AJAX requests from a browser (via `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`), the runtime knows what to do for certain request body formats and will automatically set the appropriate `Content-type` header

- If the request body is a `FormData` instance, the `Content-type` will be set to `multipart/form-data` and will also include the appropriate mime boundary tokens from the data instance.

  All of these examples will post the data as `multipart/form-data` with appropriate [mime boundary tokens](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

  ```js
  const body = new FormData();

  // attach files and other fields
  body.append("file", fileInput.files[0]);
  body.append("foo", "foo");
  body.append("bar", "bar");

  // fetch
  fetch(url, { method: "POST", body });

  // XMLHttpRequest
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url);
  xhr.send(body);

  // Axios
  axios.post(url, body);
  ```
- If the request body is a `URLSearchParams` instance, the `Content-type` will be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

  All of these examples will post the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

  ```js
  const body = new URLSearchParams({ foo: "foo", bar: "bar" });
  // serialises to "foo=foo&bar=bar"

  // fetch
  fetch(url, { method: "POST", body });

  // XMLHttpRequest
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url);
  xhr.send(body);

  // Axios
  axios.post(url, body);
  ```

You only need to manually set the `content-type` if you intend to send string data in a particular format, eg `text/xml`, `application/json`, etc since the runtime cannot infer the type from the data.

```js
const body = JSON.stringify({ foo: "foo", bar: "bar" });

// fetch
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  body
});

// XMLHttpRequest
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhr.send(body);
```

---

#### On Axios

Axios will automatically stringify JavaScript data structures passed into the `data` parameter and set the `Content-type` header to `application/json` so you only need minimal configuration when dealing with JSON APIs

```js
// no extra headers, no JSON.stringify()
axios.post(url, { foo: "foo", bar: "bar" })
```

Under the hood, Axios uses `XMLHttpRequest` so the specifications for `FormData` and `URLSearchParams` also apply.

##### Axios v0.27.1 is broken

This specific version of Axios is unable to make a proper request with `FormData`. Do not use it!

##### Axios v1.0.0+ is broken

This is verging into my own opinion but every Axios release post v1.0.0 has been fundamentally broken in one way or another. I simply cannot recommend anyone use it for any reason.

Much better alternatives are:

- The Fetch API (also available in Node v18+)
- [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) for Node.js
- [ky](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky) for browsers

##### NodeJS

When using Axios from the backend, it will not infer `Content-type` headers from `FormData` instances. You can work around this using a request interceptor.

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  if (config.data instanceof FormData) {
    Object.assign(config.headers, config.data.getHeaders());
  }
  return config;
}, null, { synchronous: true });
```

or simply merge in the headers when making a request

```js
axios.post(url, body, {
  headers: {
    "X-Any-Other-Headers": "value",
    ...body.getHeaders(),
  },
});
```

See https://github.com/axios/axios#form-data

---

#### On jQuery $.ajax()

jQuery's `$.ajax()` method (and convenience methods like `$.post()`) default to sending request body payloads as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. JavaScript data structures will be automatically serialised using [jQuery.param()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) unless told not to. If you want the browser to automatically set the `Content-type` header based on the body format, you also need to configure that in the options

```js
const body = new FormData()
body.append("foo", "foo")
body.append("bar", "bar")

$.ajax({
  url,
  method: "POST",
  data: body,
  contentType: false, // let the browser figure it out
  processData: false  // don't attempt to serialise data
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I see that I don't have to define headers in Axios as you mentioned, this is great! But your answer does not solve my issue. I still cannot post `formData` correctly. If I post `formData` without `header` as your answer in my component, everything is okay. But if I `dispatch` `formData`, `Axios` post with default header: `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. The issue is related to `Redux` maybe.

Comment: @ilvthsgm that's very strange. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68643330/edit) to show how your reducers and any middleware (sagas / thunks / etc) are wired up?

Comment: I had redundant `/` in my url, that was the problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: +1 for anyone interested in the part of the spec that requires browsers to set the `Content-Type` header for `URLSearchParams` and `FormData` see item number 6 [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#bodyinit-unions).