# how to submit data from a data form in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, form-data

I am trying to send a form to an endpoint but I get an error forbidden 403, and I already tried with an api test and the endpoint works perfectly

```
const SendData = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let respuestasUSer = new FormData();
    respuestasUSer.set('curso', state.curso)
    respuestasUSer.set('nombre', state.nombre)
    respuestasUSer.set('q1', state.Pregunta1)
    respuestasUSer.set('q2', state.Pregunta2)
    respuestasUSer.set('q3', state.Pregunta3)
    respuestasUSer.set('q4', state.Pregunta4)
    respuestasUSer.set('q5', state.Pregunta5)
    respuestasUSer.set('q6', state.Pregunta6)
    respuestasUSer.set('q7', state.Pregunta7)
    respuestasUSer.set('q8', state.Pregunta8)
    axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "https://covid.cit0.com/guardar/encuesta/",
        data: respuestasUSer,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          //handle success
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
          //handle error
          console.log(response);
        });   
}
```

In the api test I do it like this and it works for me, how could I pass this same content to axios?
[image]

Comment: First step... remove the `Content-type` header, [you don't need it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643919/283366). A 403 response suggests your authentication credentials do not allow you to request the resource in question. You don't seem to have any credentials at all in the code above so you'll need to share more information

Comment: I have added an image the way I have been able to do it with the test api

Comment: The site you're attempting to POST to requires a [CSRF token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5207160/283366) be present in a request cookie. You should be able to see the details of this in the response you get back. Basically, that site doesn't want external parties posting content. It also doesn't support CORS access

Comment: I am passing it a CSRF token but if it works in the test api, why not in my app if I am putting the same token?

Comment: Where? Your Axios request doesn't have anything like that in it. If you have the token in a cookie already, you could [try adding `withCredentials: true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43178070/283366) but I think you'll just run into CORS errors

Comment: Do not post it, but if I add the token, sorry where I add that code "withCredentials: true"

Answer (score -1):

If you are using react as front end

first you set onchange event in input text field  like

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="first name" onChange={handlechange} />
```

Create

define that handlechange function like

```
function handlechange (e) {
        const {name,value} = e.target
        setstate({...state,[name]:value}) 

}
```

//before that want to define state like const [state, setstate] = useState({})

then define handleclick function like

```
    function handleclick (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            
             axios.post('/super_admin/newuser',state).then((res)=>{
                
console.log(res.data)
                
            }).catch(err=>{

console.log(err.response.data)

})
    }
```

here is the full code

```
import {useState, } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Newuser() {

const [state, setstate] = useState({})

function handlechange (e) {
        const {name,value} = e.target
        setstate({...state,[name]:value})
    }

function handleclick (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                
                 axios.post('/your api',state).then((res)=>{
                    
    console.log(res.data)
                    
                }).catch(err=>{
    
    console.log(err.response.data)
    
    })
        }

return (

<div>
<form>
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="first name" onChange={handlechange} />
<button onClick={handleclick}>Create</button>
</form>
</div>
)

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you answered the right question? This answer doesn't seem to match anything above

Comment: i think this the way to send data using axios

Comment: he is using react from data what is the mistake bro simply giving -vote i am taking effort to give this answer ok

Comment: I think your answer is not according to my question, what you put me I already did, what I want is to send a form Data by axios and what I am sending with your answer is a JSON

Comment: check the answer if it works or not

Comment: Tips for getting upvotes: make sure your work is spell-checked, and use the correct case for sentences based on the normal writing rules for international English. If it looks like it was composed on a mobile phone, or if the code formatting is poor, then it might get downvoted. If you make a genuine effort over the long term then you will get more upvotes than down - effort is key.

Answer (score -1):

for sending form data you can edit handleclick function to something like this

```
    function handleclick (e) {
       e.preventDefault()

   const fd = new FormData()

                fd.append('first_name',state.first_name)

                 axios.post('/your api',fd).then((res)=>{
                    
    console.log(res.data)
                    
                }).catch(err=>{
    
    console.log(err.response.data)
    
    })
        }
```

Comment: why man giving -vote this is the way to send from data right

Comment: give me the response bro why you given -vote

Comment: How is this functionally any different to what OP already has? How does it solve their 403 response problem?

Comment: hey bro the meaning is same right what man he is using sendData i used handleclick what man ..?