# How to properly pass a blob from the frontend to the backend?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, frontend, blob

I'm trying to pass a blob of audio file from my `react` application to `Express` backend using formData, but I kept on getting undefined when I try to retrieve the data on the backend.

Frontend code:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fname', 'test.webm');
fd.append('data', blob);

payload = {audioFile: fd};

axios.post('/translate-audio', payload, {headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
```

backend code:

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/translate-audio', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.audioFile);
});
```

**Side note:**

I was able to see the file when I ran `console.log(payload.audioFile.get('data'));` on the frontend:

```
File {name: 'blob', lastModified: 1636600689885, lastModifiedDate: Wed Nov 10 2021 19:18:09 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 10828, …}
    lastModified: 1636600689885
    lastModifiedDate: Wed Nov 10 2021 19:18:09 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) {}
    name: "blob"
    size: 10828
    type: "audio/webm;codecs=opus"
    webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I just need to pass the blob correctly to the backend, so other alternative without using formData will be helpful as well. Also, what is a good way to do this the other way around (sending audio blob from server to frontend)?

Comment: You might also want to look at using buffers: `blob`[`.arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer)/[`.stream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream), [`express.raw`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.raw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialise `FormData` into JSON. Send the `FormData` as your request data directly and use middleware like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#readme) to handle it server-side

Frontend

```js
const fd = new FormData()
fd.append("audioFile", blob, "test.webm")

// Do not customise the content-type header.
// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643919/283366
axios.post("/translate-audio", fd)
```

Express

```js
const multer  = require("multer")
const storage = multer.memoryStorage() // or use disk storage
const upload = multer({ storage })

app.post('/translate-audio', upload.single("audioFile"), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  // see https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information
});
```

---

> Also, what is a good way to do this the other way around (sending audio blob from server to frontend)?

If you're working with files on disk, use [res.sendFile()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile), otherwise [res.send()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) is able to handle buffers.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: Is there a way to only extract the file to buffer in memory instead of saving it in local disk?I'm working with small files that are at most a few hundred KB in size.

Comment: That's exactly what my answer does by using Multer's `memoryStorage()`. The file buffer will be in `req.file.buffer`. As per my answer, see https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information