# Problem with dynamic request header in axios template

Tags: javascript, api, axios, locale

In my react app, I created an `api.js` file which creates an `api` object with `axios.create` and exports it as default. So, I use that template to make the API requests. The problem is that, one of the headers in created axios api object must be dynamic.
For example, see the `locale` header below:

At first it may be something like this:

```
export default api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
    headers: {
      post: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        locale: "en",
      },
      get: {
        locale: "en",
      },
    },
  });
```

But after some time it can be updated to some other locale, like `"en"` should be changed with `"fr"` for example. How can I update it, and make sure when it gets updated it changes in every place `api` is imported.

I can't use ContextApi etc, because I need to use that api in `index.js` file too, which, because of not being a react component, doesn't support use of hooks.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header that comes from the server. It does not belong in your request and in general will more than likely cause CORS errors. Also, the default content-type when posting JS objects in Axios is `application/json` so you typically don't need to set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [Axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)...

```js
import axios from "axios"

// some kind of storage for your locale
let locale = "en"

// some way of changing it
export const setLocale = (newLocale) => {
  locale = newLocale
}

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
})

// register a synchronous request interceptor
api.interceptors.request.use(config => ({
  ...config,
  headers: {
    ...config.headers,
    locale // merge the "locale" into the request config headers
  }
}), null, { synchronous: true })

export default api
```

Also, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header that comes from the server. It does not belong in your request and in general will more than likely cause CORS errors.

Also, the default content-type when posting JS objects in Axios is `application/json` so [you typically don't need to set it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643919/283366).