# How to set variable to API response value fetch API?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Here is the code I am working with:

```
const encodedParams = new URLSearchParams();
encodedParams.append("q", "Hello, world!");
encodedParams.append("target", "es");
encodedParams.append("source", "en");

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'application/gzip',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com',
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '3955ade317mshe662a97591d523ap1e4475jsn3bb2b223ccbb'
    },
    body: encodedParams
};

fetch('https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Here is the response I receive from the API

> {data: {…}}
> data:
> translations: Array(1)
> 0: {translatedText: '¡Hola Mundo!'}
> length: 1
> [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
> [[Prototype]]: Object
> [[Prototype]]: Object

How would I grab the `translatedText` from the API response and set a variable equal to that. I have tried `TRANSLATED_TEXT = response.data.translations[0].translatedText;`.

I need to set a variable and then put the variable into a `h1` on an HTML document. Any help with grabbing the API response would be appreciated!

Comment: response data is available .... here `.then(response => console.log(response))`

Comment: FYI the `content-type` header is [not required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643919/283366) when the body is an instance of `URLSearchParams`

Comment: try using async/await https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/

Answer (score -1):

try    response.data.translations[0].translatedText.value;

or  response.data.translations[0].translatedText[0].text;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Found a similar example: https://rapidapi.com/googlecloud/api/google-translate1/discussions/21334

Try: `response.data.data['translations'][0]['translatedText']`

Hope it helps.