# Sending array to node is taken as object using formData

Tags: javascript, express, axios, multer

I am performing an update where, in addition to other data, I need to send Node an array that includes the information of one or more images, but only their path and ID, not the image itself.

I am performing an update where, in addition to other data, I need to send Node an array that includes the information of one or more images to be deleted, but I only pass its path as well as ID, not the image itself since the images are in Cloudinary.

I use formData because among these data I send the new images in case new ones are required, but I receive all the data except for the images to be deleted, since instead of receiving an array I only receive [Object Object] and I cannot work with it. This is my code:

```
    const putProduct = async (productToUpdate, filesToDelete) => {

        console.log(filesToDelete) // Array

        const formData = new FormData()
        const imageArr = Array.from(productToUpdate.pictures)

        imageArr.forEach(image => {
          formData.append('pictures', image)
        })

        formData.append('filesToDelete', filesToDelete)
        formData.append('barCode', productToUpdate.barCode)

        try {
            const dataOnLs = localStorage.getItem('cmtjs')
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                    apiKey: dataOnLs
                }                
            } 

            const { data } = await axiosClient.put(`/products/${productToUpdate.id}`, formData, config )
```

[image: filesToDelete - Array sent from React]

I receive in Node and go through the console **req.body.filesToDelete** but it always indicates [Object Object]

```
let updateProduct = async ( req, res = response ) => {


    const filesToDelete = req.body.filesToDelete;
    console.log(filesToDelete); // [object Object]
    return
```

[image: response from Node in console]

Comment: What request body middleware have you registered? To support `multipart/form-data`, you need something like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: Yes, exactly I use Multer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormData requires objects to be strings. Here's the replacements:

**Frontend**
Replace:

```
formData.append('filesToDelete', filesToDelete)
```

With:

```
formData.append('filesToDelete', JSON.stringify(filesToDelete))
```

**Backend**
Replace:

```
const filesToDelete = req.body.filesToDelete
```

With:

```
const filesToDelete = JSON.parse(req.body.filesToDelete)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the `filesToDelete` array the same way you treat `productToUpdate.pictures`.

If you want `filesToDelete` to appear as an array in `req.body.filesToDelete`, use this...

```js
filesToDelete.forEach((f) => {
  formData.append("filesToDelete", f);
});
```

Multer automatically handles repeated fields as an array. You can optionally add `[]` to the field name for clarity in your code...

```js
formData.append("filesToDelete[]", f);
```

but the result will be the same.

---

On the client-side, you can remove the content-type header. Your browser will [handle this automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643919/283366) for you.