# Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'. vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, form-data

i'm trying to upload multiple images in vue

this the response i get after uploading the multiple files

```
{
    "0": {},
    "1": {}
}
```

this is my input tag

```html
<input
  type="file"
  @change="onFileSelected"
  multiple
  ref="files"
/>
```

this is my function

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedFile: null,
      stockQuantity: 1,
      fileName: "",
      photos: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFileSelected(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files;
      console.log(this.selectedFile);
      this.fileName = event.target.files.name;
    },
    async onAddProduct() {
      // POST request using axios with async/await
      let data = new FormData();
      for (const i of Object.keys(this.selectedFile)) {
        data.append(
          "photos",
          photos[i],
          this.selectedFile,
          this.selectedFile[i]
        );
      }
      const response = await axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/api/products", data, {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          // this.$router.push('/')
        });
    },
  },
};
```

i get both images but when i click on onAddProduct i get

> Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: What is `photos`? Do `console.log(photos[i])` at each iteration. Also, `FormData#append()` has only 3 arguments maximum.

Comment: @Kaiido not getting any response other than parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly how `selectedFile` and `photos` are defined and how they are assigned data. If you've added logging, please also update the code in your question to show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here...

1. `event.target.files` is a collection. It does not have a `name` property. Also, if you're uploading multiple files there's no point storing a single filename.
2. `photos` is never populated and doesn't appear to serve any purpose
3. [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) accepts at most 3 parameters, not 4 and you probably only need 2.
4. [Axios knows what to do with `FormData`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643919/283366), you do not need to customise the content-type header.

Really all you need for this is the following...

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedFiles: [], // plural
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFileSelected(event) {
      this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    },
    async onAddProduct() {
      const data = new FormData();

      // loop over selectedFiles and append
      for (const file of this.selectedFiles) {
        data.append("photos", file);
      }

      // no custom headers required
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/products",
        data
      );

      console.log(response);
      // this.$router.push('/')
    },
  },
};
```