# how to solve 'content-type missing boundary' and getBoundary is not a function?

Tags: javascript, api, next.js, axios, boundary

```js
getCarouselData: async (params) => {
  let bodyFormData = new FormData();
  for (let key in params) {
    bodyFormData.append(key, params[key]);
  }
  return axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `${baseURL}/getCarouselData`,
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: { "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data;};` },
  });
};
```

In the nextjs am calling the API by axios method.

1. If I set the content-type as  **"Content-Type": `multipart/form-data;`**   am getting **'content-type missing boundary'**  error.
2. If I set the content-type as **"Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${bodyFormData.getBoundary()};`** am getting  **bodyFormData.getBoundary is not a function**

3)If I remove the content-type entirely **"header:{}"**  or without header parameter am getting **"unsupported content-type"** error

How to solve this issue. But in the both methods am getting the response from the API after the error display.

[image]

[image]

But in postman am getting the result without any error
[image]

Comment: Remove the content-type header entirely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Data to Service in Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643330/pass-data-to-service-in-axios)

Comment: If I remove the content-type entirely "header:{}" or without header parameter am getting "unsupported content-type" error @Phil

Comment: Are you making the request from the browser or from Node.js? Also, what version of Axios are you using?

Comment: installed axios version is "axios": "^0.21.1",  The request send from the browser. @Phil

Comment: Can you explain why you thought that there would be a `.getBoundary()` method?

Comment: Have you customised Axios with any default headers by any chance?

Comment: I cannot reproduce any such problem with Axios 0.21.1 ~ https://jsfiddle.net/zsuj7qr9/. Please check the actual installed version of Axios... as mentioned in the duplicate, if you have 0.27.1 it won't work. Axios post v1.0.0 has also been terribly broken. I would recommend simply using the Fetch API instead

Comment: Am using nextjs serverside rendering getServerSideProps(). is that affect any API requests? @Phil

Comment: I already asked you which client was making the request (and you said the browser). If it's server-side, you need to pull the correct headers from the `FormData` instance. This is also mentioned in the duplicate

Answer (score -2):

It works fine with v1.2.2:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';

console.log(axios.VERSION);

const data = {x: "foo", y: "bar"};

let bodyFormData = new FormData();
for (let key in data) {
  bodyFormData.append(key, data[key]);
}

const {data: {form, headers}} = await axios({
  method: "post",
  url: `http://httpbin.org/post`,
  data: bodyFormData,
  headers: {"Content-Type": `multipart/form-data;`},
});

console.log('headers:', headers);
console.log('form', form);
```

Or a shorter approach:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const data = {x: "foo", y: "bar"};

const {data: {form, headers}} = await axios({
  method: "post",
  url: `http://httpbin.org/post`,
  data: data,
  headers: {"Content-Type": `multipart/form-data`},
});

console.log('headers:', headers);
console.log('form', form);
```

Log:

```
1.2.2

headers: {
  Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br',
  'Content-Length': '262',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------310666769872409476705056',
  Host: 'httpbin.org',
  'User-Agent': 'axios/1.2.2'
}
form { x: 'foo', y: 'bar' }
```