# POST. The request body is multipart/form-data with two parts, the file's bytes (file), and an optional JSON string (document) with the metadata

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, fetch-api, form-data

[image]

What am I supposed to send as the request body. I keep getting 400 Bad request. I have tried it on Postman as well as in a html file with javascript code in the script tag.

What does it mean by the file's bytes? A file as a byte array?

I also tried using postman with a key (type: file) and a file. Got BAD_REQUEST

I tried creating Blobs and converted them into byte array, append those arrays into formdata and then provide them as request body using JSON.stringify().

The current code however takes a file input from a form html tag.

Nothing seems to be working.

Also how do I write a curl command for this POST method. And how to get a document's metadata.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="FORM">
        <div>
            <label for="">File Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="FileName">
            <label for="">File:</label>
            <input type="file" id="File">
            
            <button type="submit" style="" id="submitB">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
const formData = new FormData();
        const formDataTwo = new FormData();
        const formDataThree = new FormData();

        const fileOne = new Blob(["John","117"],{type:'text/html'});
        const fileTwo = new Blob(["Commander", "Zavala"], { type: 'text/html' });
        const fileThree = new Blob(["Ikora", "Rey"], { type: 'text/html' });


        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileOne);
        var byteOne = [];
        reader.onloadend = function(e){
            if(e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE){
                var arrayBuffer = e.target.result;
                array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

            }
            for(var i=0; i<array.length;i++){
                byteOne.push(array[i]);
            }
        }

        var readerOne = new FileReader();
        readerOne.readAsArrayBuffer(fileTwo)
        var byteTwo = [];
            readerOne.onloadend = function (e) {
                if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
                    var arrayBuffer = e.target.result;
                    array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

                }
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    byteTwo.push(array[i]);
                }
            }

        




        var form = document.getElementById('FORM') 

        form.onsubmit = async (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault()
            const form = e.currentTarget;

            var readerTwo = new FileReader();
            readerTwo.readAsArrayBuffer(document.getElementById('File').files[0]);
            let byteThree = [];
            const formDataNew = new FormData();

            readerTwo.onloadend = function (e) {
                if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
                    var arrayBuffer = e.target.result;
                    array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

                }
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    byteThree.push(array[i]);
                }
                formDataNew.append('additionalProp1', byteThree)
            }

            const obj = {
                additionalProp1: formDataNew
            }
            
            

            fetch('http://localhost:8080/o/headless-delivery/v1.0/sites/20121/documents', {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                    "Authorization": `Basic ${btoa('test@oscorp.com:learn')}`
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(obj)
            })
                .then(Response => Response.json())
                .then(json => console.log(json));

        }
        
        

        // formData.append('fileOne', byteOne);
        // formDataTwo.append('fileTwo', byteTwo);
        // formDataThree.append('fileThree', byteThree);
</script>
</html>
```

The Postman api request worked after I modified the key name as instructed. But the html page still won't work. I keep getting Error code 400. My current js code is below. Also find the working Postman request screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```js
 var form = document.getElementById('FORM') 

        form.onsubmit = async (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault()
           
            const file = document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files[0];
            const metadata = {additionalProp1: "string" };

            const body = new FormData();
            body.append("file", file);
            body.append("document", JSON.stringify(metadata));

            fetch("http://localhost:8080/o/headless-delivery/v1.0/sites/20121/documents", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                    "Authorization": `Basic ${btoa('test@oscorp.com:learn')}`
                },
                body

            })
                .then(Response => Response.json())
                .then(json => console.log(json))

            }
```

Comment: _"tried using postman with a key (type: file) and a file"_... according to your screenshot you used field name `NewDoc`. Have you tried `file` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Bad API documentation, especially examples can be a real hindrance.

From reading just the description...

> The request body must be `multipart/form-data` with two parts, the file's bytes (`file`), and an optional JSON string (`document`) with the metadata.

*Update:* from comments below it seems that `document` should also be a file

I would assume you'd need something like this...

```js
document.getElementById("FORM").addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const file = document.getElementById("File").files[0];

  // this is just an example
  const metadata = { additionalProp1: "string" };

  // create a File object for the JSON document
  const doc = new File([JSON.stringify(metadata)], "metadata.json", {
    type: "application/json",
  });

  const body = new FormData();
  body.append("file", file);
  body.append("document", doc);

  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/o/headless-delivery/v1.0/sites/20121/documents", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      authorization: `Basic ${btoa('test@oscorp.com:learn')}`,
    },
    body,
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${res.status} ${res.statusText}: ${await res.text()}`);
  }

  console.log("Success!", await res.json());
});
```

Note that there is no **content-type header** added. The browser is able to provide the correct value automatically when using a `FormData` body. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643919/283366) for more details.

I think you can ignore any examples they offer. They don't appear to match the description at all.

---

In Postman, you'd use `form-data` like this

| Key | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| file | `NewDoc.txt` | A file |
| document | `metadata.json` | A JSON file |

It would be up to you to ensure `document` is properly formatted JSON.

Comment: FIrst of all I would like to thank you good sir for your guidance. Postman worked out! But I am still getting error code 400 with the html page. I would post my current code as an answer below. Please help.

Comment: @John117 I see what you've done wrong. Remove the content-type header. I've updated my answer

Comment: Yes, the code worked. I stored a .json file in the matadata variable and appended it to formdata. However, if metadata contains that object that you provided in the code above and I append that variable then it returned error code 400 even after JSON.stringify(). Why is it that content-type isn't required for this post request?

Comment: Ok, just saw your response for content-type header. Thanks for the clarification and all your help.

Comment: @John117 so you're saying that `document` needs to be a file too? That API really is poorly documented

Comment: @John117 I've updated my answer to show how to create a JSON file

Comment: Yes, that code works like a charm. But cannot upload a file with the same filename twice. Error code 409 CONFLICT. However, when there was an additional parameter in body.append("file", file, fileName) which I was getting from input type="text" tag, whenever I changed the input even if the file was same, I was getting success.

Comment: @John117 Nice, sounds like you've got it sorted then 