# Form data is always empty after sending with Axios react

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I got data:{message: 'error'} from php server in react put axios request
I actually don't know where I did wrong
as your previous answer @phil for post request it worked fine but  put has some difference so
some help would be appreciated plz

```
const handleImageChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const selectedFiles = e.target.files as FileList;
  setCurrentImage(selectedFiles?.[0]);
};

const send = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const file: any = currentImage;
  dataf = new FormData();
  dataf.append("id_userAccount",18);
  dataf.append("firstName", "acile");
  dataf.append("lastName", "Ahmad");
  dataf.append("dealerImg", file);

  // ...another string data
  axios({
    method: "put",
    url: "myurl",
    data: dataf,
   
  })
    .then(..);
};
```

i guess the error come from the server side code which looks like :

```php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=csms;", $username, $password);
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if (isset($_PUT['id_userAccount']) && isset($_PUT['firstName'])) {

    $id = $_PUT['id_userAccount'];
    $fname = $_PUT['firstName'];
    $lname = $_PUT['lastName'];
    $email = $_PUT['Email'];

    $pass = $_PUT['passWordU'];
    ...
    //$img = $_PUT['dealerImg'];

    $cogs = $_PUT['COGS'];
    $oe = $_PUT['OE'];
    $o = $_PUT['O'];
    $taxes = $_PUT['TAXES'];
    
    $putData = $database->prepare("UPDATE useraccount SET useraccount.firstName=:fname,useraccount.lastName=:lname,useraccount.Email=:email,
    useraccount.passWordU=:pass,useraccount.city=:city,useraccount.Addressu=:addres,
    useraccount.phone=:phone,useraccount.dealerImg=:img,
    useraccount.COGS=:cogs,useraccount.OE=:oe,useraccount.O=:o,useraccount.TAXES=:tax
    WHERE useraccount.id_userAccount=:id AND useraccount.type=1");

    $putData->bindParam("id", $id);
    $putData->bindParam("fname", $fname);
    //...

    if (isset($_FILES['dealerImg'])) {
        $file_name = $_FILES['dealerImg']['name'];
        $tmp_file_name = $_FILES['dealerImg']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_name, 'image/' . $file_name);
    }

    $putData->bindParam("img", $file_name);
//...

    $putData->execute();

    print_r(json_encode(array("message" => "updated")));
} else {
    print_r(json_encode(array("message" => "error")));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php://input` is for parsing plain text payloads like `application/json`. Use `$_POST` and `$_FILES` to access `multipart/form-data` request body data.

```php
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
// etc

if (isset($_FILES['dealerImg'])) { // "dealerImg", not "file"
    // ...
}
```

Also, [you don't need to set the content-type request header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643919/283366). Your browser will do that for you and the value you are currently using is incomplete.

```js
axios.post("myurl", dataf).then(...)
```

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/283366) for a more robust PHP / CORS implementation