# Configure Axios configure the validateStatus function once per project?

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm using the following code to prevent axios from returning an error when the response is not in the 200 range:

Here is what I have now:

```
import axios from "axios";

function doSomething() {
   var options = { headers: { "Content-Type" : "application/json" }, validateStatus: () => true };
   var response = await axios.post(url, form, options);
}

function doSomethingElse() {
   var options = { headers: { "Content-Type" : "application/json" }, validateStatus: () => true };
   var response = await axios.post(url, form, options);
}
```

Here is what I want:

```
import axios from "axios";

var options = { headers: { "Content-Type" : "application/json" }, validateStatus: () => true };
axios.use(options);

function doSomething() {
   var response = await axios.post(url, form);
}

function doSomethingElse() {
   var options = { headers: { "Content-Type" : "application/json" }, validateStatus: () => true };
   var response = await axios.post(url, form, options);
}
```

Currently I pass in this object every call. I'd like to set this preference once.

Comment: Your code is invalid. You can only use `await` within an `async` function

Comment: Sorry, I went to format your code with Prettier to remove the horizontal scrolling and it complained so I just left it

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach is to [create an Axios instance](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance) with your preferred defaults.

For example

```js
// http.js
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
  validateStatus: () => true,
});

export default instance;
```

The `create()` method accepts all the same options as `axios()`.

Your consuming code can then use this module instead of Axios directly

```js
import axios from './http';

// ...

axios.post(url, form);
```

FYI there's hardly ever a reason to set global `content-type` headers. Axios has many faults but setting the appropriate type headers based on request body data isn't one of them.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643919/283366) for a more in-depth look at when you *should* and *should not* manually set `content-type` headers.

Comment: ok i can remove that. it was part of an answer i see now that it doesn't make sense to have it global.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Stack Overflow is littered with questions and answers with entirely unnecessary HTTP headers. Somewhere along the line, everyone started adding `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers without knowing why and it just stuck

Comment: I haven't seen anyone use a default export in the wild. And in this case, that makes sense. Good job

Comment: @1.21gigawatts not sure what you mean by that. You were literally already using the default export from Axios

Comment: no i meant that you were creating an instance and then making it available as an export. but if axios is doing that already i didn't realize that but i guess it is. i don't know if this counts as a singleton or not...