# body empty while sending HTTP POST request from JavaScript to node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, npm

Am making an XMLHttprequest fromjavascript to my node server.

this is my request:

```
        var data = { "fname": "Fasal", "lname": "Rahman" };
        var body = JSON.stringify(data);
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "/admin");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send(body);
```

this is my post rout:

```
app.post("/admin", function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.body);
});
```

I am using body-parser

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

the body i am getting from the request from the server is like this

`{ '{"fname":"Fasal","lname":"Rahman"}': '' }`

the entire body json as the key and  value as `''`

i need the body to be in key value pair like this
`{fname:"Fasal",lname:"Rahman"}`

which is the correct way of sending JSON object?

Comment: Your method appears to be POST but your handler is get.

Comment: sorry that was a typing mistake while I am raising the question, edited the question.

Comment: Why are you setting the Content-type header to something other than application/json?

Comment: ```var data = { fname: "Fasal", lname: "Rahman" };```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I POST a x-www-form-urlencoded request using Fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325370/how-do-i-post-a-x-www-form-urlencoded-request-using-fetch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Content-type header should be "application/json":

```
const data = { "fname": "Fasal", "lname": "Rahman" };
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "/admin");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: when i do so am getting empty object ```{ }```

Comment: Suspect your body parsing. You can use `app.use(bodyParser.json())` or simply `app.use(express.json());` if you have Express 4.16+.