# Fetch Post Request with Parameters is returning 400 status code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have a Post Request using fetch in react native, but I get a status code 400 for this, what is wrong with the code?

```
function sendRequest2() {
    fetch(`https://sandbox-api.dexcom.com/v2/oauth2/token`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        code: "value1",
        client_id: "value2",
        client_secret: "value3",
        redirect_uri: "http://www.google.com",
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("The error is: " + err));
  }
```

Comment: can you try by not JSON.stringify the data? That step does not seems to be required.

Comment: Remove the image, and then try to URLEncode the body instead of stringify. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63501847/1702612

Answer (score 0):

Check your content-type, replace it by :

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
```

helpfull link : [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

Comment: I did it. I am getting a status code of 415

Comment: 1 - remove JSON.stringify as said above and define a variable object (containing your data ) oustside your body scope then set it to your body scope. retry , hoping it'll runing well..

Comment: 2 - if it still same , i think something going wrong with your data datatype, so check them carefully. Good luck !!

Comment: I’m still facing this problem with application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Yeah, it’s openid oauth2 keycloak server required, so cannot change to other type. I code in reactjs, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by removing JSON.stringify

That would solve the issue

Moreover you have shared a lot of open information regarding your server openly.

You must either hide it or add some dummy values. Sharing such a secure data openly is not recommended in open community.

Comment: I removed the JSON.stringify by still getting a status code 400 :(

Comment: what type of program is this? Is this node.js code? If so you would need some additional setting using body-parser ... here is example code from 

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html


var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())