# invalid_code when authorizin slack oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, slack-api

I'm generating an **authorization link**:

```
var url = `https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=*****.*****&redirect_uri=http://localhost:6001/code/slack&state=${state}&scope=channels:read,bot`
```

In the **redirect endpoint**:

```
var url = 'https://slack.com/api/oauth.v2.access';
  var data = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'client_id': "*****.******",
    'code': req.query.code,
    'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:6001/code/slack'
  };

  axios.post(url, data, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
  }).then((response: any) => {
    console.log(response.data)

  }).catch((error: any) => {
    res.status(400).json(error.response.data);
  });
```

However, when I'm receiving this error for some reason `{ ok: false, error: 'invalid_code' }`

Could it be because I have a http redirect point? I don't think so because I'm able to receive the code and state in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this https://api.slack.com/methods/oauth.v2.access

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

client_secret is required.
code may have to be decoded from URL encoding

Comment: Client Secret is optional and when I changed the content type I got { ok: false, error: 'invalid_form_data' }

Comment: This is how the code looks like in my redirect endpoint query 3382854632534.3405002874401.0fa0c731a5107280809570bbd8a431dad0389329097156eee455d7cccdf67834 is this normal?

Comment: The code looks OK. Are you sending JSON - it will not be accepted? client_secret may be optional in native app scenario with PKCE.

Comment: I'm sending the data object as noted above and tried removing the strings from the keys in the data object

Comment: That will not work :( You need key=value&key=value string url encoded

Comment: Do you mind giving me an example how to do it with axios in your provided answer?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325370/how-do-i-post-a-x-www-form-urlencoded-request-using-fetch

Comment: Im getting bad client secret now.. i thought it's optional

Comment: and even if I included it I started getting oauth_authorization_url_mismatch becasue im using http instead of https :/

Comment: It appears that you are using Slack's OAuth2 protocol as described here: https://api.slack.com/legacy/oauth. You are authorising at https://slack.com/oauth/authorize. Therefore you have to exchange code for token here: https://slack.com/api/oauth.access Valid scopes are here: https://api.slack.com/legacy/oauth-scopes.  I do not see this scope in the list:  channels:read,bot

Comment: Removing the bot scope wouldn't fix the main problem I'm facing rn which is the request needs to be sent to a https endpoint.

Comment: Yes, Slack requires redirect_url to use https. However, I am happy to confirm that the token exchange does work from command line using Httpie: http --form POST https://slack.com/api/oauth.access client_id=XXXXX client_secret=XXXXX code=XXXXX redirect_uri=https ://localhost:8010.

Comment: The corresponding auth request: https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXX& scope=channels:read& redirect_uri=https ://localhost:8010&state=1

Comment: The access endpoint you shared belongs to the legacy module. i,e ( NEW https://slack.com/api/oauth.v2.access).

Comment: I think it will be an overfill to setup https on my express server for this. Any idea how to work around it?

Comment: Does this help: https://medium.com/@esplo/an-easy-to-use-proxy-to-access-https-localhost-6cfcf8602e6b

Comment: Very interesting resource.. thanks for sharing. I'm not sure how to configure it on pipeline s

Comment: I believe this is beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: Hahahaa true, I might post a question and I’ll let you know how it goes :) thanks a lot 

Comment: No worries. I believe I answered the original question. May as well accept my answer.